# PHPStorm Xdebug always breaks on first line

Tags: php, phpstorm, breakpoints, xdebug

I've setup Xdebug with the following configuration:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55-xdebug/2.2.5/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable= "On"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = "Off"
xdebug.profiler_enable = "On"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

and using "remote debugging" with the [Xdebug](https://github.com/benmatselby/xdebug-toggler) toggler plugin for safari.

But in PHPStorm it always breaks on the first line even though I have no breakpoint set there. I have looked in the settings of and found a setting related to this. But I have unchecked those. But even after a restart it still breaks on the first line of the first file.

[image: PHPStorm settings]

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Run | Break at first line in PHP scripts` -- try turning it ON and OFF **few times**. Sometimes it is get stuck in between: showing OFF but in reality it is ON.

<s>If this solves your issue .. then -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17389 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.</s> This particular moment has been **fixed since PhpStorm v9**.

---

If you still having such issue (IDE breaks an first line) and the above does not help ... then it has nothing to do with this option/answer and it's some misconfiguration at another place (missing or wrong paths mappings and stuff like that).

Comment: That indeed was the problem. It was ticked even though the checkmark was not visible.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have a problem with it turning on/off just the fact that this setting does not exist inside the actual debugger settings - just randomly in this menu

Answer (score 21):

You can find the option in `Run` menu, it's at the bottom. 
[image]

Answer (score 7):

And my solution was to uncheck

- Force break at first line when no path mapping specified
- Force break at first line when a script is outside the project

under `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug` ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114762/how-to-stop-xdebug-from-stopping-on-first-line-with-phpstorm)).

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For those who are stil having the problem, I solved mine by editing the file:

.idea/workspace.xml

and looked for the PhpDebugGeneral component and manually entered "false" to the xdebug flags there.

`<component name="PhpDebugGeneral" break_at_first_line="false" ...`

It looks like some leftover from the upgrade in my project.

Comment: Seemed promising, but there is no such entry in my `workspace.xml` file. PHPStorm 2016.2.2.

Answer (score 4):

All the above didn't work. The problem in my case was: The file which has the `first line` was in a directory which was **excluded**. This is why it sayd: `The script ..path-to-script/index.php` is outside the project. Even though it is not.

If you click on `Click to set up mappings` and then toggle the directory from `File Directory` on local machine you will see the directory which is `Excluded` is not listed here.

The fix was to `un-exclude` the directory having the file with the first line. And exclude all contents inside. You can easily do this with right clicking on the directory > Mark Directory as > Cancel Exlusion and the same to exclude the other content inside right click > Mark Directory as > Excluded

[image]

Comment: This was the cause for me as well

Comment: Same here, thanx it drove me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was a wrong path mapping 
make sure that the directory of your project is opened in the IDE

Comment: This was the problem for me too.  If you've tried all the checkboxes above there is a good chance that this is the cause.  In PHPStorm the settings are under Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried these steps:

- step 1: uncheck these two options at xdebug section

[image]

- step 2: copy & paste the directory of your project at `/xampp/htdocs/{your-project}`

[image]